# error: value split is not a member of Char

Tags: scala, apache-spark

import spark.implicits._

```
case class x(Data_time_Occured:String,Duplicate_Count:Int,Message:String)

val Final_df1=Final_df.map(_.split(",")).map(x=> (x(0).trim.toString,x(1).trim.toInt,x(2).trim.toString)).toDF("Data_time_Occured","Duplicate_Count","Message")
```

====VALUE IN fINAL_DF is==== :
`Final_df: String = 13/4/2020,0`
No Duplicate records has been loaded in Sql table .Kindly keep monitoring the load

Answer (score 1):

"Final_df" type can be changed to Seq:

```
val originalString = "Data_time_Occured1,4,Message1"
val Final_df = Seq(originalString)
Final_df.map(_.split(",")).map(x => (x(0).trim.toString, x(1).trim.toInt, x(2).trim.toString)).toDF("Data_time_Occured", "Duplicate_Count", "Message")
```

Comment: Worked :), Thanks very much Pasha, i will let you guys know in case of any further assistance:)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a  map operation on the single string value and then applying a split on that. Map operation will convert this string into individual char and then you are trying to apply a split option on individual character which is why you are getting this error.

If you want to split this string on the basis of comma, here is how you can do it.

```
val Final_df1 = Final_df.split(",")
```

This will resolve your error and then you can apply your transformations to move forward as per your requirement.

Please accept the answer if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Im trying to Split that String based on Comma, and im trying to create Dataframe with 3 headers to store those splited values

Comment: When I'm trying to Create dataframe , still errors out. PFB!!​

val Final_df1 = Final_df.split(",").toDF("Data_time_Occured","Duplicate_Count","Message")



error: value toDF is not a member of Array[String]
val Final_df1 = Final_df.split(",").toDF("Data_time_Occured","Duplicate_Count","Message")

Comment: Do it like Pasha suggested

Comment: @manoj: please accept the answers if it resolves your issue or post the issue you are facing now

Comment: Final_df2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("table1")
​



error: value write is not a member of Unit
Final_df2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("table1")

Comment: I dont find any, issue can yu please suggest why system cnt able to write the dataframe

Comment: Please raise a new question with the error you are getting because the answer for your original question has already been provided