# error: value write is not a member of Unit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

## DataFrame output:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
|Occurence_Date|Duplicate_Count|             Message|
+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
|     13/4/2020|              0|No Duplicate reco...|
+--------------+---------------+--------------------+

Final_df2: Unit = ()
```

## Code:

```
Final_df2.write.csv("/tmp/first_par_to_csv.csv")
```

## But erroing out:

```
error: value write is not a member of Unit
Final_df2.write.csv("/tmp/first_par_to_csv.csv")
```

Comment: Please share you full code, And you might be applied show() on top of "Final_df2" . Becuase of that you are getting the error.

Comment: Correct Goutam, i used show in this line =>Final_df2=Final_df1.map(_.split(","))
.map(x => (x(0).trim.toString, x(1).trim.toInt, x(2).trim.toString))
.toDF("Occurence_Date", "Duplicate_Count", "Message") ,   ...What is the reason for that?   ..... My issue is fixed now

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is the further extension of [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184292/error-value-split-is-not-a-member-of-char) posted by the same user

I am assuming you get the Final_df2 by doing a show on Final_df1 as provided in the previous question which is what is being told by Goutam.

To resolve this and in continuation of your previous post, here is what you need to do:

```
val originalString = "Data_time_Occured1,4,Message1"
val Final_df = Seq(originalString)
val Final_df1 = Final_df.map(_.split(",")).map(x => (x(0).trim.toString, x(1).trim.toInt, x(2).trim.toString)).toDF("Data_time_Occured", "Duplicate_Count", "Message")
Final_df1.write.csv("//path//to//your//destination//folder")
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get this issue when your DF object is incorrect, e.g.:

```
var df = spark.read.csv("file:///home/praveen/emp.csv").show
df.show
```

When you do `df.show()` obviously you get error, because `var df` object is already containing `show` method at EOL. You cant do again `show` method on df explicitly.

So what I'm saying is your `Final_df2` is incorrect. To debug this I need to know how you created your `Final_df2` object.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way:

```
val df= spark.sql("select * from Table")
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("orc").saveAsTable("Table_name")
```